# Syntax error with mySQL query function to convert decimal grade to a letter grade

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

I'm having troubles with a syntax error when trying to create a function in MySQL to convert a decimal grade into a letter grade.

What could be the issue?

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'conv(gpa DOUBLE)
>   RETURNS CHAR
>   BEGIN
>   DECLARE grade CHAR;
>   SELECT CASE WHEN gp' at line 1

Here is my code:

```
delimiter $

CREATE FUNCTION conv(gpa DOUBLE) 
RETURNS CHAR
BEGIN 

DECLARE grade CHAR; 

SELECT CASE WHEN gpa BETWEEN 3.5 AND 4.0 THEN 'A' 
WHEN gpa BETWEEN 3.0 AND 3.4 THEN 'B' 
WHEN gpa BETWEEN 2.5 AND 2.9 THEN 'C' 
WHEN gpa BETWEEN 2.0 AND 2.4 THEN 'D' 
ELSE 'F' 
END INTO grade 

RETURN grade;

END $
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a semi-colon near the end:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN gpa BETWEEN 3.5 AND 4.0 THEN 'A' 
WHEN gpa BETWEEN 3.0 AND 3.4 THEN 'B' 
WHEN gpa BETWEEN 2.5 AND 2.9 THEN 'C' 
WHEN gpa BETWEEN 2.0 AND 2.4 THEN 'D' 
ELSE 'F' 
END INTO grade;
```

Also, you probably shouldn't use the name `conv` as this is already means [something else](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv).

Comment: Thanks! I tried the semicolon before but it was just the name of my function! Thanks much! :)